# Creating a Stop Watch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

I want to create a timer/stop watch in javascript for the following use case:

On clicking the "Play" button, i start the stop watch and on clicking "pause" it's stopped. Then the diff gives me the elapsed time. From this, I should show the song progress time and update it. If the song is fully played, then, the timer should start from the beginning (i.e. 0 level) else, it should start from the state where it has stopped.
Please guide me how to do it in javascript. How to get the current time? (gettime??)

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this to show the current position of an audio file being played, just use the audio element's `currentTime` attribute, which is constantly updated with the pointer's location.

Alternatively, the most basic stopwatch simply records `new Date().getTime()` when started, and again when ended and returns the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('play').onclick = function() { window.played = +new Date(); }
document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function() {
    var difference = (+new Date() / 1000) - window.played / 1000 < songLengthInSeconds;

    if (difference > songLenthInSeconds)
        // code for start from the beginning
    else

        // code if not fully played yet
}
```